# Aerospike : (Flash/SSD device + data-in-memory:true)

Tags: aerospike

I am exploring Aerospike for one of my projects. Have configured device as my storage-engine (*ssd* ("~250GB")). *RAM* per box in the cluster is "~50GB".

**My question** : Will setting "*data-in-memory true*" give any significant boost to the cluster performance ? I tried benchmarking writes to the Aerospike cluster first by setting  "*data-in-memory true*", than "*data-in-memory false*". There was no significant boost/drop in the performance. Does it really makes sense to  put "data-in-memory true" here (alongside an SSD). Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the impact on writes is not going to be noticeable, in fact, it probably will be exactly the same. `data-in-memory true` will boost read performance by having those served out of memory as opposed to from storage. Finally, you can also check the post-write-queue setting to have in-memory performance on reads for records that were recently inserted/updated.

Comment: Thanks. just rephrasing a little bit, what advantages would i get by "data-in-memory true" in an SSD setup. (Memory would be a very expensive approach given the amount of data is > 1TB).

Comment: "data-in-memory true will boost read performance by having those served out of memory as opposed to from storage". Is this the sole advantage of having the data in memory. (I would love to compromise with a couple of milliseconds hit in my reads VS consuming 1TB of redundant RAM).

Comment: Depends on your read and write workloads. You should benchmark your workload (both read and write) to see if you really need `data-in-memory true`. From your comment, especially the 2ms compromise, it sounds like SSD config should be fine (assuming acceptable SSDs). Do make sure to check the `post-write-queue` config. If you read soon after you write, this will give you in memory read performance for all those reads.